# Cannot create SingleCellExperiment object after convert 'SYMBOL' to 'NCBI ID'

Tags: r

I follow the online scTensor tutorial to analyze the 10x Genomics data from pig. After I convert 'SYMBOL' to 'NCBI ID', I cannot create SingleCellExperiment object. If I don't do the conversion, there is not any problem. Could you help me to figure it out? Thank you.

> ```
> R version 3.6.2
> scTensor version 1.2.1
> ```

```
pc.data <- Read10X(data.dir = ".\filtered_feature_bc_matrix\")    

for_sc <- as.matrix(pc.data)

rowID <- rownames(for_sc)

LefttoRight <- select(org.Ss.eg.db, column=c("SYMBOL", "ENTREZID"), keytype="SYMBOL", keys=rowID)
##'select()' returned 1:many mapping between keys and columns

for_sc <- convertToNCBIGeneID(for_sc, rowID, LefttoRight)

11563 of genes are removed from input matrix (25880*3011),
and only 14317 of genes are kept.

pc <- CreateSeuratObject(counts = for_sc, project = "pc", min.cells = 3, min.features = 200)

pc <- NormalizeData(pc, normalization.method = "LogNormalize", scale.factor = 10000)

Performing log-normalization
0% 10 20 30 40 50 60 70 80 90 100%
[----|----|----|----|----|----|----|----|----|----|
**************************************************|

pc <- data.matrix(pc, rownames.force = NA)

Error in as.vector(data) :
no method for coercing this S4 class to a vector

pc <- as.matrix(GetAssayData(pc, slot = "counts"))

sce <- SingleCellExperiment(assays=list(counts = pc))

Error in validObject(.Object) :
invalid class "SummarizedExperiment" object:
'names(x)' must be NULL or a character vector with no attributes

names(pc)

NULL

sce <- as.SingleCellExperiment(pc)

Error in UseMethod(generic = "as.SingleCellExperiment", object = x) :
no applicable method for 'as.SingleCellExperiment' applied to an object of class "c('matrix', 'double', 'numeric')"
```

Comment: hey did you check whether convertToNCBIGeneID is meant for a seurat object?

Comment: Hi, I found convertToNCBIGeneID and seurat are not compatible. Thank you for the comment.

Comment: Yup.. Just change the rownames of for_sc. You have problems with that?

Comment: Yes, could you please tell me the detail? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the error because when you map the names, it is a named vector you are assigning as rownames of the matrix. Try this below:

So let's say we have a count table like below:

```
library(SingleCellExperiment)
library(Seurat)
library(org.Ss.eg.db)
set.seed(100)
GENES = sample(keys(org.Ss.eg.db,keytype="SYMBOL"),1000)
counts = matrix(rpois(1000*20,100),ncol=20,nrow=1000)
rownames(counts) = GENES
colnames(counts) = paste0("cell",1:20)
head(counts)
```

We convert the rownames to entrez id :

```
ENTREZIDS = mapIds(org.Hs.eg.db,rownames(counts),keytype = "SYMBOL",column = "ENTREZID")
ENTREZIDS = as.character(ENTREZIDS)
table(is.na(ENTREZIDS))
FALSE  TRUE 
  527   473
```

Sometimes you have genes not in entrez and this returns NA. So you either subset your matrix to have only entrez genes, and create Seurat:

```
newcounts = counts[!is.na(ENTREZIDS),]
rownames(newcounts) = ENTREZIDS
sboj = CreateSeuratObject(newcounts)
sexpr = SingleCellExperiment(assays=list(counts = newcounts))
```

Or, you keep them

```
newcounts = counts
rownames(newcounts) = ENTREZIDS
rownames(newcounts)[is.na(ENTREZIDS)] = rownames(counts)[is.na(ENTREZIDS)]
sboj = CreateSeuratObject(newcounts)
sexpr = SingleCellExperiment(assays=list(counts = newcounts))
```

Comment: No problem @qq2006tom. Glad it helped. If you feel that the answer solved your problem, you can think about accepting the answer by checking the checkmark next to an answer. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work. Thanks and have a great weekend :)